# unable in removing an element using iterator

Tags: java

I had entered three elements using vector and was trying to remove the specific elemnts from the list but was unable to do so.

I am getting the following error while compiling:

**iterator.java:28: error: 'void' type not allowed here
                  {System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());}
                                                       ^
1 error**

Where am i doing wrong.

```
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.lang.*;

  class iterator
  {
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
  Vector<Integer> v= new Vector<Integer>();
  //Vector<String> v= new Vector<String>();
  v.addElement(new Integer(10));
  v.addElement(new Integer(20));
  v.addElement(new Integer(30));

 //v.addElement(new String("mayank"));

  //v.addElement(new Boolean(true));
  //Enumeration e = v.elements();
   Iterator i = v.iterator();
   while(i.hasNext())
      {
       System.out.println(i.next());
       }
       try{
           v.remove(10);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());}
      //System.out.println("Remove error exception");}
    while(i.hasNext())
      {
       System.out.println(i.next());
       }


     }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`e.printStackTrace()` does all that you need. Since it returns a void, you essentially have a println trying to print a void which doesn't work (and doesn't make sense either).

Solution: Get rid of the `System.out.println`. Simply call `e.printStackTrace()`.
Better yet, use logging.

---

**edit:** Also, to remove the Integer with the 10 value, consider doing:

```
remove(new Integer(10));
```

so that the JVM doesn't think that your remove parameter represents the index position of the item you wish to remove.

---

**Edit 2:** Note that contrary to your question title, you are **not** using the iterator to remove anything.

---

**Edit 3:** removing without using iterator

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

class HisIterator {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();

      v.addElement(new Integer(10));
      v.addElement(new Integer(20));
      v.addElement(new Integer(30));

      Iterator<Integer> i = v.iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(i.next());
      }
      try {
         v.remove(new Integer(10));
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println();
      i = v.iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(i.next());
      }

   }
}
```

---

**Edit 4:** with iterator

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

class HisIterator {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();

      v.addElement(new Integer(10));
      v.addElement(new Integer(20));
      v.addElement(new Integer(30));

      Iterator<Integer> i = v.iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) {
         Integer nextI = i.next();
         System.out.println(nextI);
         if (nextI.equals(Integer.valueOf(10))) {
            i.remove();
         }
      }
      // try {
      // v.remove(new Integer(10));
      // } catch (Exception e) {
      // e.printStackTrace();
      // }
      System.out.println();
      i = v.iterator();
      while (i.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(i.next());
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Indeed. And it clearly says: **print**. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace())

Comment: i want to remove the 10 element from the list but the code doesnot do so

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels can i remove the element with the help of iterator

Comment: +1, though I would use `Integer.valueOf(10)` instead of `new Integer(10)`, which is (according to the javadoc) "likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values"

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels please guide me how to remove using iterator

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an inherent ambiguity. The remove function is by element index not element value. The program will attempt to remove the 10th (zero based) element not the element with value 10.

The fact that the vector value types are integers makes things more confusing.